# how to define an element in XML schema if it present in a set of range

Tags: xml, xsd

How can i define an element in XML schema for eg

an element A can be present between 1-100 400-450 600-700 only.
Values others than these range must ne rejected at the time of validation

thanks for quick reply
I tried in this way

`<xs:element name="verification">`
`<xs:simpleType>`
`<xs:union>`

```
<xs:simpleType>
 <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
  <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
  <xs:maxInclusive value="100" />
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType>
 <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
  <xs:minInclusive value="200" />
  <xs:maxInclusive value="250" />
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType>
 <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
  <xs:minInclusive value="600" />
  <xs:maxInclusive value="610" />
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>


</xs:union>
```

`</xs:simpleType>`
`</xs:element>`

but its not working accepting values like 125 and 500 also and not showing validation error

Comment: It works for me just fine (copied&pasted your code). I am using Visual Studio 2010 to execute the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define three subtypes of integer one for each of the value ranges (using minInclusive and maxInclusive), and then define a type that is the union of these three.